# How to carry value over from function in other file after button click - PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I am new to PyQt5 and user interfaces in general, and I believe the below problem is due to a fundamental misunderstanding of how buttons work.

I have two python files; *file_1* contains my functions:

```
def prepare_ht_data():
    data = [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]
    ]

def prepare_ndt_data():
    data = [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]
    ]
```

And *file_2* contains my user interface code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from file_1 import prepare_ht_data, prepare_ndt_data

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
MainWindow.setWindowTitle('NJM Hour Calculator')
MainWindow.resize(540, 465)
MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(540, 465))
MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(540, 465))
MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);\n"
"}")

central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

frame_1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(central_widget)
frame_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 521, 91))
frame_1.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}")

frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(central_widget)
frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 521, 251))
frame_3.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}")

pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(frame_1)
pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 141, 31))
pushButton_1.setText('Heat Treatment')
pushButton_1.clicked.connect(prepare_ht_data)

pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(frame_1)
pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 141, 31))
pushButton_2.setText('Non-Destructive Testing')
pushButton_2.clicked.connect(prepare_ndt_data)

pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(frame_3)
pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 170, 151, 31))
pushButton_3.setText('Next')

tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(frame_3)
tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 331, 201))
tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Time', 'Direction'])

header = tableWidget.horizontalHeader()    
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

print(data)

MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**This results in:**

[image]

**My Problem:**

When I try to run *file_2* I would expect the ui to open, allowing me to click either `pushButton_1` or `pushButton_2`, assigning the variable 'data` the matrix in the functions, and then printing 'data'. Instead, I get `NameError: name 'data' is not defined`.

**My Question:**

I understand that, by not pushing the button, the function is not being run, and therefore 'data' is not defined, but why does this happen? And how can I carry this over without running either `prepare_ht_data()` or `prepare_ndt_data()` more than once? In real life these functions are quite complex and cannot be run multiple times.

If I place `print(data)` at the very end of the ui script, the buttons do nothing.

The end goal is to be able to use the 'next' button (`pushButton_3`) to iterate through the data, populating the table widget with the contents at each index.

I have been following: https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/ but have been unable to solve the issue.

Comment: `data` is local to the functions in which it is defined. Assuming you were to click the buttons, `data` would come into existence, and then immediately get garbage-collected once the callback ends. Its lifetime is bound to the scope of the function it was created in, and referring to `data` in any other scope will naturally result in a `NameError`. The callbacks should perform all desired side-effects, such as printing. Also, why do you expect your `print` statement to wait for you to press a button?

Comment: So, just to confirm my understanding of what you've said, ```prepare_ht_data()``` and ```prepare_ndt_data()``` should perform any actions (such as printing the data). So if I would like to begin iterating through the data and populating the table, I would have to do so within the function being called by the button?

Comment: @ChaddRobertson The point is that UI frameworks are generally event driven and can be usually better implemented when doing subclassing, instead of trying some sort of "procedural" workflow: this allows better control and access to objects, including iterating through data that is used to fill fields, performing some form of interaction based on it or even keep persistent references of objects (including your `data`, for instance) that can be more safely accessed or manipulated.

Comment: @musicamante Understood, so implementing subclasses should be my first step. This style of programming is completely foreign to me, so I appreciate the helpful response.